# Creating a bash/shell script to capture output from Traceroute command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have been working to prepare a script which can help in monitoring a WAN Link with the traceroute command.

- A script to grep an Primary WAN IP from traceroute and if found echo Primary is UP.
- If Primary IP not found, grep secondary IP in traceroute and echo Primary down, secondary UP.
- If both the IP's are not found, echo PRimary and Secondary are down

---

I prepared something of this sort, but couldnt get it work..

```
 echo "`traceroute  4.4.4.4>/tmp/trace.txt`"
 grep  “1.1.1.1” /tmp/trace.txt &> /dev/null
 if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
     echo  “Primary Is UP“
 else
 grep  “2.2.2.2” /tmp/trace.txt &> /dev/null
 if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
     echo “ Primary failed, Secondary Running”
else
     echo "Primary & Secondary both failed"
 fi
 fi
```

Comment: ```echo "`traceroute  4.4.4.4>/tmp/trace.txt`"```. Is your script supposed to run the traceroute command? In this case, it should be just 'traceroute  4.4.4.4>/tmp/trace.txt'

Comment: Thanks Loris, I have removed the double quotes  and also found few spaces and quotes issues which i fixed.. it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick test, don't use traceroute if you don't need it.
Instead try ping with the Record Route (-R) option.
Use the -c option to only make one request, and the -n option to not resolve the route hostnames, and the -W option to not wait too long for failure.
Perhaps something like:

```bsh
if ping -R -n -c1 -W2 4.4.4.4 >/tmp/trace.txt
then
    #echo something is up
    if grep -q '\<1\.1\.1\.1\>' /tmp/trace.txt
    then
        echo  Primary Is UP
    elif grep -q '\<2\.2\.2\.2\>' /tmp/trace.txt
    then
        echo  Primary failed, Secondary Running
    else
        echo "Primary & Secondary both failed, but something else Running"
    fi
else
    echo "Primary & Secondary both failed"
fi
```

It is possible you might need to convince one or more routers to honor record route.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `echo` and the quotes in the first line of your script, just leave the command `traceroute`. Your script should be written as:

```
traceroute .... 
grep .....
...
```

Comment: One of my friend also suggested to use egrep and both the matching IP's in it using pipe.  Some what like this         egrep "169.254.255.17|169.254.255.146" /tmp/trace.txt &> /dev/null                      but i couldnt figure out how to get that work with matching parameter  If [ ]